# Tree recommendation for Christmas

Tags: indoors, plant-recommendations

Well, Christmas is coming, and I'd like a Christmas tree.

But I hate the idea of having to throw it away every year.

So I'd like a tree which

- would be happy in a tree pot,
- can live indoors,
- at least vaguely resembles a Christmas tree (so maybe a conifer)
- stays green in winter
- can withstand some decorations
- doesn't grow too big (2 m high would be a maximum)

Does such a tree exist ?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. Whilst you might find a dwarf coniferous tree that you find an acceptable substitute for a christmas tree, it won't cope with being indoors year round, it will need to be outdoors for most of the year, only being brought into the house over Christmas for a short period of, say a week, two weeks maximum, and even then in as cool a spot as you find in the house. As well, a conifer that wants to reach 2 metres will not thrive long term in a pot either, though, depending on the variety of tree, it may do okay for up to five or six years so long as you're prepared to pot it on as necessary. Given that's the case, you could just buy a small christmas tree in a pot, keep it outdoors most of the time, potting on as necessary, and that should, with care, last maybe 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe best to regard a Christmas tree as you would any any other vegetative crop. Use it, then get rid of it. Or buy a plastic tree, which will last for years.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have great luck with Norfolk Pine Araucaria heterophylla.   I have not grown it myself, but I have seen it in many people houses living for years.  They can't hold very many ornaments, but can hold a few. Here is a webpage on care of a Norfolk Pine
https://[www.guide-to-houseplants.com/norfolk-island-pine.html](https://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/norfolk-island-pine.html)